# I can't access my current element

Tags: javascript, variables, object, global-variables, jointjs

This is an instance of Rappid Toolkit which uses jointJS for building visual tools as for web development. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XSis.png

In this toolkit you can make a graph which can become a website.

My problem is the following one:

In every single element of this graph there is a box below it with:x,y,width,height,angle.

I want to change this information of this boxcontent and to display some info from this element but the code in which I have to add my snippet is the following(var Halo is the var for my element in the graph):

```
var halo = new joint.ui.Halo({
                cellView: cellView,

                boxContent: function(cellView) {


                     return"Here I want to display my box content info instead of x,y,width,height, angle";
                }
            }).render();
```

If I try to add my code inside it to access in JSON format my current element info my full code is:

```
var halo = new joint.ui.Halo({
                cellView: cellView,

                boxContent: function(cellView) {
            // Drawing
            var selectedObjectDataText = JSON.stringify(this.cellView.toJSON());
        var selectedObjectDataJSON = JSON.parse(selectedObjectDataText);

                     return(selectedObjectDataJSON[0].wi_name);
                }
            }).render();
```

where **wi_name** is the name of my element but in the first line I can't access the specific element of my graph.

```
var selectedObjectDataText = JSON.stringify(this.cellView.toJSON());
```

Is there any global way to access my halo(my graph element) since **this.cellView.toJSON()** doesn't work?
I tried **this.model.toJSON()** **this.cellView.model.toJSON()** etc with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for `var selectedObjectDataText = JSON.stringify(cellView.model.toJSON());`

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Note that JointJS `links` and `elements` are Backbone Models *(`linkView` and `elementView` are Backbone Views)*.

To get the current value of an attribute use [`get()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) method.

```js
boxContent: function(cellView) {
    return cellView.model.get('wi_name');
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`prop()`](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:prop), that can return also nested properties of a model.

```
boxContent: function(cellView) {
    return cellView.model.prop('wi_name');
}
```